# How to avoid target "leaking" into the training process with PyTorch's TimeSeriesDataSet and TemporalFusionTransformer?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, prediction, transformer-model

Basically, I have a time series dataset that wants to predict the price 14 days from now. There are dozens of features and everything is being trained with TemporalFusionTransformer (PyTorch version).

Originally, I trained to predict price every day for the next 14 days, however these gave fairly poor results. So, I want to switch to predict ONLY the price 14 days from now. For a conventional dataset I would just lag the price variable 14 days (dataset['price_lagged'] = dataset['price'].shift(-13) and set max_prediction_length to 1 to predict the 14th day) and set this as a target variable.

Current code that still predicts well (and it shouldn't):

```
training = TimeSeriesDataSet(
    dataset[lambda x: x.day <= training_cutoff], 
    time_idx="day",
    target="price_lagged",
    group_ids=["group_id"]
    min_encoder_length=max_encoder_length ,
    max_encoder_length=max_encoder_length,
    max_prediction_length=max_prediction_length,
    static_categoricals=[],
    static_reals=[],
    time_varying_known_categoricals=[],
    time_varying_unknown_reals=[
        #I removed EVERYTHING from here
    ],
    time_varying_unknown_categoricals=[
],
    time_varying_known_reals=[  
],
    target_normalizer=EncoderNormalizer(),
    #lags=lags,
    add_relative_time_idx=True,
    allow_missing_timesteps=False,
    add_target_scales=True,
)
```

However, the model seems to use the target as a variable as well. I can see this if I literally remove every other feature, I still get a fairly good prediction. How can I explicitly have the model NOT use the target as a (obvious) feature? Can TFT work like this?